# How to Use a Custom Ingest Pipeline with a Filebeat Module

Tags: elasticsearch, filebeat

How do I use a custom ingest pipeline with a Filebeat module? In my case, I'm using the `apache` module.

According to multiple sources, this is supposedly configurable via `output.elasticsearch.pipeline` / `output.elasticsearch.pipelines[pipeline]`. Sources follow:

- https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/elasticsearch-output.html#pipelines-option-es
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/58726519/1026263
- https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/elasticsearch-output.html#pipelines-option-es

However, after many attempts at different permutations, I have never been able to influence which ingest pipeline is used by the Filebeat; it *always* uses the module's stock ingest pipeline.

This is just one of the many attempts:

```yaml
filebeat.config:

filebeat.modules:
  - module: apache
    access:
      enabled: true
      var.paths: ["/var/log/apache2/custom_access*"]
    error:
      enabled: true
      var.paths: ["/var/log/apache2/custom_error*"]

filebeat.config.modules:
  reload.enabled: true
  reload.period: 5s

output.elasticsearch:
  hosts: ["${ELASTICSEARCH_URL}"]
  pipeline: "apache_with_optional_x_forwarded_for"
```

Running filebeat with debug (`-d "*"`) shows the following, which, I assume, demonstrates that my specification has been ignored. (I can also tell by the resulting docs in Elasticsearch that my custom pipeline was sidestepped.)

```json
2021-12-16T23:23:47.464Z      DEBUG   [processors]    processing/processors.go:203    Publish event: {
  "@timestamp": "2021-12-16T23:23:47.464Z",
  "@metadata": {
    "beat": "filebeat",
    "type": "_doc",
    "version": "7.10.2",
    "pipeline": "filebeat-7.10.2-apache-access-pipeline"
  },
```

I have tried this in both Filebeat v6.8 and v7.10 (in the docker.elastic.co/beats/filebeat docker images).

---

This is similar to these threads, which never had a satisfactory conclusion:

- [How to use custom ingest pipelines with docker autodiscover](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68700592/how-to-use-custom-ingest-pipelines-with-docker-autodiscover/70384615#70384615)
- [How to specify pipeline for Filebeat Nginx module?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58654560/how-to-specify-pipeline-for-filebeat-nginx-module/58726519#58726519)

Answer (score 0):

Well, according to this [PR](https://github.com/elastic/beats/pull/16561) to on the beats repository, to override the module pipeline you need to specify the custom pipeline in the `input` configuration, not on the `output`.

Try this:

```
filebeat.modules:
  - module: apache
    access:
      enabled: true
      input.pipeline: your-custom-pipeline
      var.paths: ["/var/log/apache2/custom_access*"]
    error:
      enabled: true
      input.pipeline: your-custom-pipeline
      var.paths: ["/var/log/apache2/custom_error*"]
```

Comment: Your answer led me to [the right spot in the docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/6.8/filebeat-input-log.html#_pipeline) for the module `input.pipeline` However, the docs also mention that this is doable in the [`output`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/6.8/elasticsearch-output.html#pipeline-option-es), as well, which maybe is a broken feature. I'll try it in the module config next week to see if that actually functions as documented. Thanks for the reply, @leandrojmp.